# List or Array with a text as its Index?

Tags: vb.net, data-structures

Using vb.net, is it possible to have a list of values such as:

```
Green
Black
Blue
```

and the index to be a text value such as

```
Table
Desk
Chair
```

something like this

```
ListColors("Chair")="Green"
ListColors("Desk")="Blue"
ListColors("Table")="Black"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary(Of String, String)` object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx